# How to find & delete an obscure file of which I only know the name?

Tags: search, macos

Sophos detected a trojan which it cannot remove on Mac OS 10.4 and it says to remove it manually. Problem is, it gives the file name as `xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx` where the `x`'s are hex digits. No directory path, no nothin—just the digits.

How do I find and delete this file?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the given file name?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the report from a single scanner to be definitive. When you do locate the file have it checked by one of the on-line scanners, such as http://www.virustotal.com, for confirmation. Sophos has a very poor track record for false positives.

Answer (score 11):

There are a variety of ways of searching for a file by name.  I'd just open the Terminal and run `locate xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx`, although the locate index is only updated once a week, so if it's a new file it might not be listed.  If you want, you can manually force an update with `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` (you'll need to enter your admin password for the `sudo`).

You can use Spotlight in the Finder, but it leaves out system files by default -- there's a way to change this, but it's a little complicated and may not be the same in 10.4. (EDIT: instructions for doing this in 10.6 are in [Apple's KB #HT4355](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4355).)

Finally, you could use the `find` command: `sudo find / -name xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx` -- this will require your admin password for the `sudo`, and will be slow (it actually looks at all your files to find a match), but should find things the other options might miss.

Comment: I'm upvoting the 'sudo find' option.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this next time I see this user. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: `sudo find / -name xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx 2> /dev/null` is preferable tbh

Answer (score 1):

If your mac has spotlight, `mdfind` is a much better command line too for locating a file.

Next in speed / efficiency would be locate (which uses a typically week old cached version of the `find` command to index files)

Lastly the slower `find` to crawl the directory from a root folder you wish to begin the search.

All the tools can fail to find files, mdfind has built-in exclusions (few and mostly system cache and internal files), locate can be out of date and excludes sone files by rule as well, find of course needs permission to traverse directories so it can fail to find files that have restrictive permissions.

---

You can of course use the finder to search spotlight (which is basically what `mdfind` does) and ask to include system files assuming your file is squirreled away in some temporary folder and not being found by the default spotlight settings... <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [EasyFind](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html) and [Find Any File](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/) (of which I'm the author, incidentally). Both search for file names on entire disks. They search even in places where Spotlight never looks (e.g. in the System and Library folders). In case of Find Any File, you can even easily search as root user, so that it even finds files usually not accessible to you.

Both tools are also better than the "locate" command because they search the *current* disk catalog, while locate only looks inside a database that needs regular updating - so it won't find files that were only just created, e.g. after installing some new software via an installer.

And both are much *much* faster than using the find command.